# Complicated pricing regex with multipliers and various formats

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that looks for prices in a comment line that can be formatted differntly (depending on the person who entered them

```
REG / SZ / 236,30 SUMMER
```

should match 236.30 (rather easy)

```
WB / SZ / 187.75 EBS
```

should match 187.75 (could have done that by myself so far)

here are the tricky ones

```
FS / EBS / 1*145.80 + 231.30
FS / EBS / 1x 145,80 + 231
FS / EBS / 3x 145.80 + 4x231
FS / EBS / 3* 145.80 + 4x231
```

First should match 145.80 and 231.30
Second should match 145.80 and 231.00
Third should match 145.80 and 231 and possibly "4x" and "3x"
Fourth as third with * AND x

Is there any way to do that with a regex?

//EDIT (clarification)
I want to have a total sum in the end. So third and fourth case would be (3*145.80) + (4*231). Second case is intentionally 145,80 instead of 145.80.

What I got so far

```
(([0-9])*?\.([0-9])*)|(([0-9])*?\,([0-9])*)
```

Which will give me 236,30,  187.75, 145.80, 145,80

Comment: It is not clear what you want in the third and the fourth cases. Also please show what you have already tried.

Comment: but its `145,80` not `145.80`

Comment: edited initial question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from re import findall

examples = ('REG / SZ / 236,30 SUMMER', \
            'WB / SZ / 187.75 EBS', \
            'FS / EBS / 1*145.80 + 231.30', \
            'FS / EBS / 1x 145,80 + 231', \
            'FS / EBS / 3x 145.80 + 4x231', \
            'FS / EBS / 3* 145.80 + 4x231')

for line in examples:
    numbers = findall(r'[/+]\s*(?:(\d+[.,]?\d*)[*x ]\s*)?(\d+[.,]?\d*)', line)
    result = 0.0
    for multiplier, value in numbers:
        if not multiplier:
            result += float(value.replace(',', '.'))
        else:
            result += float(multiplier) * float(value.replace(',', '.'))
    print '%s\nAfter regex: %s\nResult: %.2f\n' % (line, numbers, result)
```

Produces the result:

```
REG / SZ / 236,30 SUMMER
After regex: [('', '236,30')]
Result: 236.30

WB / SZ / 187.75 EBS
After regex: [('', '187.75')]
Result: 187.75

FS / EBS / 1*145.80 + 231.30
After regex: [('1', '145.80'), ('', '231.30')]
Result: 377.10

FS / EBS / 1x 145,80 + 231
After regex: [('1', '145,80'), ('', '231')]
Result: 376.80

FS / EBS / 3x 145.80 + 4x231
After regex: [('3', '145.80'), ('4', '231')]
Result: 1361.40

FS / EBS / 3* 145.80 + 4x231
After regex: [('3', '145.80'), ('4', '231')]
Result: 1361.40
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an input such as 1*[VALUE] is fine by you, I believe the following will catch all numeric statements:

> (\d[x*] ?)?\d+([.,]\d+)?(?![*x])

---

Here's the breakdown:

> (\d[x*] ?)?

Catches optional multipliers

> \d+([.,]\d+)?

Requires the numeric value, with an optional decimal value

> (?![*x])

Is a negative lookup to invalidate standalone multipliers as accepted values (e.g. match 1x as the value 1).

Hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Thanks that helps. It's giving me `(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 236,30
        [1] => 187.75
        [2] => 1*145.80
        [3] => 231.30
        [4] => 1x 145,80
        [5] => 231
        [6] => 3x 145.80
     )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 1*
        [3] => 
        [4] => 1x 
        ...
     )
 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => ,30
        [1] => .75
        [2] => .80
        [3] => .30
        [4] => ,80
        ...
     )

)`

Comment: this is the array your regex is giving me. It only gives me the numbers after . and , (e.g. ,30 not the total amount of 236,30 instead). Tested with http://www.myregextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify it and have a regex to capture the part trailing last `/`

```
(?<=\/)\s[\dx\*\+\.\,\s]+
```

It would give all the numeric parts and then you have to evaluate the expression.